# Merge two colums result as single colum data using Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to get all record data as single column using SQL query.

```
User Table
user_id     username    parent_id
10          user1       5
12          user2       3
14          user3       2
..          ..          ..
```

get all users with parent id as single column
Need results as below (get data from user_id & parent_id)
users    OR     users
10              10
12              5
14              12
5               3
3               14
2               2
..              ..
Here just need list of user sequence is not important.Is this possible in sql query? is there any SQL function for that?

Comment: `SELECT user_id FROM ... UNION SELECT parent_id FROM...` you may need to tweak slightly for distinct users.

Comment: Did you try UNION or UNION ALL?

Comment: Is there any kind of logic about when something appears on the left, when on the right, and when both times?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
SELECT user_id AS users FROM Users
UNION
SELECT parent_id AS users FROM Users
```

Use `UNION ALL` if you need duplicate values (such as in the `parent_id` column) to return as individual rows. Make sure the alias is the same for both halves to get it to return in a single column. This will return unordered, so rerunning the query might not always give the same result (meaning same data in same order), but it will always give the same data.